# php mysql select for organizational chart / multi level structure

Tags: php, mysql

I have build my user table like this:

[image]

Now I would like to select the 3 blue rows.
I have build the following function:

```
function display_children($parent, $array = array()) {
  global $db;

  $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id AS man, parent_id FROM user WHERE parent_id= ?");
  $stmt->execute(array($parent));
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    display_children($row['man'], $array);
    $array[] = array("man" => $row['man'], "parent_id" => $row['parent_id']);
    echo $row['man']."\n"; //for debug
  }
  return $array;
}
print_r(display_children(50001));
```

My Output is:

```
50002
50004
50003
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [man] => 50002
            [parent_id] => 50001
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [man] => 50003
            [parent_id] => 50001
        )

)
```

The first three lines are correct, but the array is missing one.
The problem is, that the first parent_id has two rows. But the array is empty at the beginning. Is there a solution for my query?

Comment: The issue you have is that the record for 50004 doesn't have 50001 as their parent.  You could add an additional aspect to the where clause, but that would only add one level; you'd need to keep adding levels for different size organisations.  Instead, you'd need to go through the results, and for every record with 50001 as their parent, get their children, and their children, and so on until you've got the whole structure

Comment: thats the reason why I call the function within the function again: `display_children($row['man'], $array);`

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to change the following line from

```
display_children($row['man'], $array);
```

to

```
$array = display_children($row['man'], $array);
```